# how to call same activity from Intent Android?

Tags: java, android

How to Call Same Activity From Intent in firebase onChildChange ?

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
     try {
        Intent i= new Intent(PlaceholderFragment.this,PlaceholderFragment.this);
     }
     catch (Exception e){}
}
```

How to Call Same Activity From Intent?

Comment: Simply call `startActivity(new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourActivity.class));`

Comment: but it is not allowing to use same activity.

Comment: Are you trying to call an Activity or Fragment?

Comment: Actually I want to refresh the same Activity When some Data Update on Firebase database.

Comment: Then instead of recreated the same activity, try to use an `interface` to communicate with your `activity` from `fragment` to refresh the `view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity, YourActivity.class);
i.startActivity();
```

Or you can simply use:

```
getActivity().recreate();
```

Comment: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(com.example.iqeq_lighthouse.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment, java.lang.Class<com.example.iqeq_lighthouse.ui.main.PlaceholderFragment>)

Comment: My bad, didn't see you are on a `Fragment` check the updated code

Answer (score 0):

You can call same fragment from itself as follows.

```
PlaceholderFragment newFragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layoutContainer, newFragment , "New Fragment");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("New Fragment");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```